# In iOS app ,can i copy bundle resources to sandbox's tmp directory with XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode

i want to copy some files to the app's tmp directory when the xcode package the app , so when the user install the app , the files is be put in the tmp directory already , but in xcode 's copy bundle resources , the files can't be copied to the tmp directy , is there anyway to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I understand that you're trying to make several files be put in the tmp directory at app install time.

Unfortunately, that is not possible. The iOS creates 3 containers upon an app installation as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

- Bundle Container: This is where the app gets installed
- Data Container: Creates 3 separate folders where the app can store data
- iCloud Container: Where iCloud specific data can be saved

> Workaround

You can simply check every time the app launches to see if it's the first time the app launches and manually copy the files to your destination. You can use a Boolean in your app's `NSUserDefaults` to check whether the app was installed before.